# neo4j, condition "has at least one label from a specified set"

Tags: neo4j

Consider a database with movies nodes that can have one or more language specified as labels; in each user node there is specified an array of languages he speaks.

What's the best way to search for movies in the languages spoken by the user (using a condition like "has at least one of these labels")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your movies carry a `Movie` label and a label for each language they're available, e.g. `en`, `fr`, `de`

If your looking for all movies being available in English or French:

```
MATCH (m:Movie) 
WHERE any(l in labels(m) WHERE l in ['en','fr'])
RETURN m
```